# Windows 10 pinned folder behavior

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar

In windows 8 I was able to pin a folder to the taskbar and when I right clicked my mouse over it I was given give a list of recently accessed folders and also able to pin them.  Now, after upgrading to Windows 10, I can't.  All I get now is "File Explorer" (to open my computer), "Unpin from Taskbar" and "Close Window".  I REALLY appreciated this shortcut.  Can anyone help?[image]

Comment: This is very much a feature of Windows 10 - I just checked. So what do you see when you right click file explorer on the task bar, could you add a screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem,
Right click on your Task Bar and un-check "Lock the Taskbar"

[image: Make Sure TaskBar is unlocked]

Drag and Drop the folder you wish to pin onto your taskbar

[image: What It Should Look Like]

Then Right-Click on your file explorer it should then appear like this

[image: Pinned!]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it wasn't locked. Locking it and unlocking it made no difference.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what happens when you try to follow these steps?